# How can i find value with same unique code php

Tags: php

i have this array online dictionary example

```php
$output = [];
$results = $db->query("SELECT language,uniqueid,description FROM dictionary_text")->rows;

foreach($results as $row) {
    $description = $row['description'];
    $language = $row['language'];
    $uniqueid = $row['uniqueid'];
    $output[] = [
        'uniqueid'  => $uniqueid,
        'language'  => $language,
        'text'      => $description
    ];
}
```

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [uniqueid] => 87964330e78
            [language] => 1
            [text] => how
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [uniqueid] => 87964330e78
            [language] => 2
            [text] => sidee
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [uniqueid] => b6cf53d6841
            [language] => 1
            [text] => comes
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [uniqueid] => b6cf53d6841
            [language] => 2
            [text] => kaalis
        )

)
```

i use search input to find [how], when found i want to get the other text from same unique code array. how can i do that

Comment: Your English are not good and your description cannot be understand. Could you please provide an example of the output you want based on the data output you show us ?

Comment: Do it directly in SQL, using in example a subquery such as : `SELECT ... FROM yourtable WHERE uniqueid IN (SELECT uniqueid FROM yourTable WHERE text = 'how')`

Comment: @Cid You are genius, thank you so much

Comment: @KodeFor.Me Thank you [Cid] method worked for me